# How to select multiple words between delimitations

Tags: javascript, regex

My brain has overheated. Have you got an idea how can I select **`:words to select`** in these following text with a Regexp in javascript?

```
Begin :word1 word2: free text :word: :words to select :done:
```

My actual Regex is :

```
/\B:([\-+\w]*)$/g
```

Each terms is delimited by colon like `:wordexample:` or `:multiple words:` and I just want the words beginning with a colon, not ending by a `:`
So, the difficulty is to exclude the good terms surrounded by colon...

I'm working on a textcomplete with multiple words and having problems with the selection of multiple words.

Comment: [`:\s*(:[^:]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/pL7tU8/1). Use `$1`.

Comment: With Begin :word1 word2: free text :word: free :words to select :done:
Your regex found nothing :/

Comment: Does this work for you `:([^\s][^:]+\s):` ?

Comment: It seems better but one more thing needed, don't choose the : at the end and should take multiple words. The text is not always the same, i have to select only the words followed by the colon to launch a research, hope you understand the complexity of the terms selection? 2 examples: 1) :word is closed when surrounded by colon: 2) :word or words begin with colon and use to launch research

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I can get:

```
/(?::)((\b\w+\b(?!:)) )+(?::)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work: `/:\S[^:]*(?=\s:|$)/g`

Regex101 can explain it better than I can: https://regex101.com/r/fA2vP9/2

> : matches the character : literally
>
> \S match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
>
> [^:]* match zero or more of a single character not that isn't the literal character :
>
> (?=\s:|$) Positive Lookahead - Assert any white space character [\r\n\t\f ] followed by the character : literally OR assert position at end of the string
>
> g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

Using the following strings with `.match(/:\S[^:]*(?=\s:|$)/g)`, you get the following outputs:

#### Example 1

```
"Begin :word1 word2: free text :word: :words to select :done:"
output> [":words to select"]
```

#### Example 2

```
"Begin :word1 word2: free text :word: :words to select :done: :test :test:"
output> [":words to select", ":test"]
```

#### Example 3

```
"Begin :word1 word2: :i :free: text :word:"
output> [":i"]
```

#### Example 4

```
"Begin :word1 word2: free text :word"
output> [":word"]
```